# One word for "proactive changing of behaviour"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need to find one word for "changing behaviour". The word should imply proactive change (in behaviour) and not reactive change (such as adapting or the likes). It has got to do with changing behaviour of customers.

An example usage:

> The "proactive change" of the consumer result in benefits such as lower premiums, incentives as well as improved health

Comment: Could you expand at all? It's not quite clear what you're asking.

Comment: Paradigm shift ?

Comment: _Temperamentality_ in one of its senses might work, but the main sense involves mercurialness and/or moodiness. It also refers to the character trait giving rise to the changing behaviour.

Comment: I one word to substitute "changing behavior" with one word. The word needs to have a meaning (along the lines of, but not limited to...) that implies a pro active change in the behavior of a customer, to benefit himself

Comment: Who does the changing: Do you want to express you change the customer's behaviour, or do you want to express that the customer changes their own behaviour?

Comment: @oerkelens if you can give both sides then that would be awesome.

Comment: hehehe :) If I could I would have done so already :) I was trying to narrow down the question :) Still thinking :)

Comment: Im thinking on the lines of a word thats an antonym to manipulate (behaviour), hence the proactive side (as manipulation has a sense of reactivity to it

Comment: What about *habituation*?

Comment: How about "cultivate" as opposed to manipulate? Or "inculcate" even. However, these words should be followed by appropriate objects and related parts of speech.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be exactly one word for this but there are ways to convey this idea:

> The consumer **took initiative** and lowered premiums, better incentives, and improved health.

But the most appropriate word for what you are looking for *is* "proactive" and I don't see anything particular wrong or ugly about "proactively changed" or "proactive changes":

> The consumer's proactive changes resulted in benefits such as lower premiums, better incentives, and improved health

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a sentence with "proactive change" where you want your new word to be?

Off the top of my head, I would say the following all connote "positive proactive change", ordered from most to least fitting:  Evolution, innovation, advancement, adjustment, and depending on the context maybe transition as well.

Comment: The "proactive change" of the consumer result in benefits such as lower premiums, incentives as well as improved health

Comment: I think 'evolution' is pretty strictly a reactive process.

Answer (score 0):

**Reform** is pretty close:

> **Reform:** to make changes in (something, especially an institution or practice) in order to improve it.

Though it's quite a formal, institutional-sounding term - it doesn't sound very friendly, though it is specifically about improvement. I think you still need to be clear that it's the behaviour you're talking about, so your example could become:

> This reform of the consumer's behaviour results in benefits such as lower premiums and incentives as well as improved health.

*(Grammar tweaked slightly)*

Answer (score 0):

I would use **compliance** in this situation.

From the context you are saying that if the consumer is compliant with the program, it results in lower premiums, improved health, etc.

This appears to be a health and wellness related usage. And, when speaking of proper behavior amongst patients you use the term *compliant.*

I would assume that you have some sort of goals that the consumer should achieve in order to qualify for these benefits. It seems unlikely that you would just reward random acts of good behavior.  Therefore, you must have a series of beneficial behaviors you wish the consumer to adopt. (Smoking cessation, etc.)

Compliance with the program goals results in …

Answer (score -1):

`Influence on customers`. Influence — the capacity to have an *effect on* the character, development, or *behavior* of someone or something, or the effect itself. ©

Comment: That's not even a _reactive_ change **in** the customer.